# How to get mouse position on two screen

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing an UWP application, that include two window pages on two displays.
I want to get the mouse position(x,y) on the secondary screen into a text block on the first screen at the same time.

I do the following code but the result is just " x = 0".

```
 MainPage.xaml.cs

    public double Xpage2;
    textblock.Text = $" X = {Xpage}";
```

---

```
Page2.xaml.cs

MainPage mainpage = new MainPage();

private void CoreWindow_PointerMoved(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)

        {
            Point ptr = args.CurrentPoint.Position;
            mainpage.Xpage2 = ptr.X;
        }
```

How can I get the mouse position(Xpage) on another screen?

I need a solution to get the position value of `Point ptr` from another class to the variable `Xpage2` ,simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to change Xpage2 in a `(new MainPage())` object rather than using the existing MainPage object.

> MainPage mainpage = new MainPage();

Do not create new MainPage object as it will not contain the one created while navigation. Instead, pass the existing object while navigating to page2 like below

#### In MainPage

```
CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
   .....
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2),this) // this means existing MainPage object.
   ....
}
```

Then receive the existing object by using `e.parameter` in `OnNavigatedTo` event.

#### In Page2

```
MainPage mainpage;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   mainpage = e.Parameter as MainPage;
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Now you can set `mainpage.Xpage2 = ptr.X;` It will reflect in the exsisting object.